# What is the name of this thorny flowering plant?

Tags: identification

This plant has thorns, thin leaves and has purple flowers. This plant grows in Charlotte, NC, US. This plant is about 6-12 inches. This plant started growing on it's own. I think this plant is an annual but I'm not sure because I haven't saw this before.
[image: Whole plant]

[image: Flower]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a thistle. There are a few possible specific species. Some are considered noxious weeds in certain states. Some are native species in some locations.

Presuming you are in North Carolina, *as you have oddly left your state out of your location*, https://www.invasive.org/species/list.cfm?id=21 includes Canada Thistle as an invasive/noxious weed, and that might well be what this is, but I'm not sure of making a positive ID (of which exact thistle species it is) from these pictures.

Comment: I am, its definitely thistle.  @Green, you should chop it down before it starts forming seed.